# Rails 4, Heroku, Comparing times not working

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, time

Using Heroku, I am trying to compare a saved times (open and close) of a place to the current time to determine what to output.

**Code:**

```
  def get_place_search_display(open_time, close_time)
    open_time_formatted = open_time.strftime('%l:%M %p') if !open_time.nil?
    close_time_formatted = close_time.strftime('%l:%M %p') if !close_time.nil?
    current_time = Time.current #.strftime('%l:%M %p')

    if open_time.nil? || close_time.nil?
      "Closed today"
    elsif current_time < open_time
      "Opens at #{open_time} until #{close_time}"
    elsif current_time >= open_time && current_time <= close_time
      "Open #{open_time} - #{close_time}"
    elsif current_time > close_time
      "Closed at #{close_time} today"
    else
      "Open until #{close_time} today"
    end
  end
```

**Example returned values:**

Open time: 7:00 AM

Close time: 8:45 PM, 2000-01-01 20:45:00 UTC

Current time: 6:35 PM, 2014-09-07 18:35:36 -0700

Returns: "Closed at 2000-01-01 20:45:00 UTC today"

Any ideas what the comparison isn't working using this logic?

Comment: you're comparing strings, not times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the term "today" in your output string, and also the `'%l:%M %p'` in your time formatting method, I assume you are trying to **compare Time objects without Date info**

However in Ruby, Time object always comes with date. But you can achieve that by converting them into the same day before comparing them.

```
a = Time.current
=> Mon, 08 Sep 2014 02:30:44 UTC +00:00
b = Time.current.months_ago(1)
=> Fri, 08 Aug 2014 02:30:59 UTC +00:00
a > b
=> true
a2 = a.change(day:1, month:1, year:2000)
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 02:30:44 UTC +00:00
b2 = b.change(day:1, month:1, year:2000)
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 02:30:59 UTC +00:00
a2 > b2
=> false
```

Hope it helps.